# What causes Bad Audio Performance during Video Playback using a WPF MediaElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I've searched high and low for a steer on this issue.

When I setup a C# WPF MediaElement to play a MP4/WMV video in test project, the video plays and the audio sounds fine.

When i try the same in my actual project, the video jumps and the audio pops and clicks (not in unison).

Can anyone offer a solution for this issue, or at best a debugging strategy?

Thanks

Comment: I once had a similar issue -- you can probably try these: 1) check if there are any overlays on the video of your actual project, overlays (especially gradient etc) will greatly increase the memory and processing power required to playback. 2) try converting the video to a lower resolution (and probably stick to mp4 and h.264 encoding), and see if the problem persists.

Comment: that was it! Basically, i noticed that the image i had behind the video had an OpacityMask set to Black, rather than none. While this shouldn't make a difference to the video overlayed on top, for some reason it did!

Comment: Great! Glad that it could be solved.